# Is this sentence a passive construction?

Tags: passive

This sentence appears in today's [DW Langsam gesprochene Nachrichten](https://www.dw.com/de/08052021-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-57469018):

> Die Lage des FC Augsburg im Abstiegskampf der Fußball-Bundesliga hat sich auch durch die Rückkehr des Trainers Markus Weinzierl nicht entschärft.

The translation I am given by Google is:

> The situation of FC Augsburg in the relegation battle of the Bundesliga has not been defused by the return of coach Markus Weinzierl.

which appears to be a sentence with a passive construction. But the grammar I see does not correspond with any passive construction with which I am familiar.
And I cannot find evidence that entschärfen can be used as a reflexive verb. So I try to use Google again to understand the grammar:

> Es hat **sich** durch die Rückkehr nicht entschärft: The return did not defuse it.

> Es hat durch die Rückkehr nicht entschärft: It hasn't defused by the return.

Google indicates the presence of sich makes it passive!?

Isn't the use of werden required here for a passive construction?

> Es ist durch die Rückkehr nicht entschärft **worden**.

And why is the **sich** present in this sentence?

Comment: Even if, it would be "Es **ist** ...entschärft worden"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all: *hat sich entschärft* is morphosyntactically an **active** and reflexive verb form. The reason is the following:

By default, *etw. entschärfen* is a transitive verb, so we have two arguments:

> Die Rückkehr entschärft den Konflikt.
> *The return defuses/eases the conflict.*

In those sentences, the one who defuses (*agent*) is the subject and the thing that is defused (*patient*) is the object.

Some transitive verbs, among them *entschärfen*, have another, intransitive form with only one argument: the patient, i.e. the former object. The patient then becomes the subject of the sentence:

> Der Konflikt entschärft sich.
> *The conflict eases.*

The intransitive form is called [*anticausative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticausative_verb), hence the process is called [*causative alternation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causative_alternation#German). In German, the *anticausative* does not have its own morphosyntactical forms, but is usually identical with reflexive verbs.

English also has verbs with causative alternation, e.g. *to ease, to open and to break*. English does not use the reflexive form to mark the anticausative, but the alternation itself works the same way. We already see it above when we look at *to ease*. Another example:

> He opens the door.
> The door opens. *(in German reflexive: öffnet sich/'opens itself')*

Comment: Remark to the last example: "öffnen" exists als in a properly intransitive form, i.e., apart from  *Er öffnet die Tür* and *Die Tür öffnet sich*, there is also *Der Laden öffnet (montags immer um 8 Uhr)*.

Comment: The jargon can be confusing here. Wiktionary allows "ergative" to be used when transitive and intransitive switch subjects, for example in the entry for *ankohlen*. I personally think it's clearer to just list the meanings separately, as in the entry for *aufbrechen*, especially if such labels aren't used consistently. But Wiktionary does have a habit of never using "cat" when *Felis catus* will do.

Comment: @RDBury The terminology of that is supremely fuzzy (and debated), especially on joint works like Wikipedia and Wiktionary where it changes between articles. There was a controversy about using the term *ergative* for those verbs at the end of the 60s, and the main counter-argument is that it should be reserved for the [case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_case). Also, the distinction between *ambitransitive* and *anticausative* verbs is not very clear. In German, I would say, it's whether the verb forms become reflexive (anticausative) or not (ambitransitive) after the alternation.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: Interesting, I didn't know the term was controversial, just that it was confusing to have multiple words (all unfamiliar to the layman) describing very similar things. To me, grammar is a shortcut to learning a language, and while it's certainly an interesting field in its own right, it's not one I have time to master on top of learning that language. (German is challenging enough.) So while a certain amount of grammatical jargon is useful, I'm suspicious of learning new terms that might not help with the main goal.